# Using match function with colour criteria

Tags: vba, excel, colors, find, match

I'm trying to find the row of a cell with the usage of match. I've been able to do this with

```
rowfound = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("123", Range("A:A"), 0)
```

But here come's where i'm stuck at. The "123" may have appeared multiple times in the same column (these would have been filled with a colour already) and i'm trying to find the latest "123" cell. This cell would not be filled with any colour.

I've tried to input it this way but i believe `Interior.ColorIndex = 0` only applies to objects and not ranges.

```
rowfound = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("123", Range("A:A").Interior.ColorIndex = 0, 0)
```

I've also tried doing a `Selection.Address` on the uncoloured cells and doing a match from there but this will results in the match function giving a result that isn't the row of where the cell is in the worksheet (it'll give the row that it can be found in the selection) [i.e actual cell row of "123" = 2000 but result given is "1", which is the row in the selection]. My code for this is

```
RRR = Selection.Address
rowfound = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("123", Range(RRR), O)
```

Any idea how to solve this? Hope i was clear in my explanation of my issue.

Comment: Not sure what makes you think you can use Match like that. You can use the Find method with a format though.

Comment: Use a Range.Find in conjunction with the SearchFormat parameter to find the relevant cell

Answer (score 0):

You can use Range.Find's "After" parameter to keep going further until you match the Interior.Color you want.

I made a little snippet to demonstrate what I mean:

```
Sub test()
Dim blankCode As Long
Dim tempRange As Range
Dim lookupValue As String

blankCode = 16777215 'Blank cell
lookupValue = "testing this out" 'what im looking for
Set tempRange = Range("A1") 'Starting in cell A1

Do
'Going through each match of the lookup value until the color is what we need
    Set tempRange = Range("A:A").Find(lookupValue, After:=tempRange)
    If tempRange.Interior.Color = blankCode Then
        MsgBox ("Found it on cell " & tempRange.Address)
        Exit Do
    End If

'This will loop indefinitely if the value isn't there, so I'd add a loop control that suits your project
Loop While True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I did my solution as a function that works pretty similarly to the regular `Match` function:

```
Public Function MatchUncolored(lookup_value, lookup_array As Range)
Dim cell As Range, ct As Long

For Each cell In Union(lookup_array.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), lookup_array.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas))

    ct = ct + 1

    If ct > 10000 Then
        MatchUncolored = "#ERROR"
        Exit Function
    End If

    If cell.Value = lookup_value And cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
        MatchUncolored = ct
        Exit Function
    End If

Next cell

End Function
```

Seems to work with what I tested it on, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another approach.  This one uses the Find method to search for a match.  Also, it too uses a function to return the the row number.  However, if there's no match, it returns an error for which it can be tested.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim vRow As Variant
    vRow = FindUncolored("123", Range("A:A"))
    If IsError(vRow) Then
        MsgBox "No match found!", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Match found in Row " & vRow, vbInformation
    End If
End Sub

Function FindUncolored(strSearchFor As String, rngRange As Range)

    Dim rngFound As Range

    With Application.FindFormat
        .Clear
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With

    With rngRange
        Set rngFound = .Find(what:=strSearchFor, after:=.Cells(.Rows.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, _
            lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True)
    End With

    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        FindUncolored = rngFound.Row
    Else
        FindUncolored = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    End If

    Application.FindFormat.Clear

End Function
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Application.FindFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
rowfound = Range("A:A").Find("123", SearchFormat:=True)
```